# Where to download Mars DEMs and landcover?

Tags: data, dem, exogeography, mars

I'm looking on the websites of the Mars Global Surveyor and the NASA sites, but all of the data is in jpeg or img form. Does anyone know where to find useful raster data sets for elevation and land cover (soil types)? I'm sure the information is sparse, since the entire planet has not been covered.

Comment: Uh oh, new field? migrate to Areographic Information Systems stackexchange?

Answer (score 5):

There are several resources available according to a basic Google search on "Mars GIS data". For instance:

- [USGS Planetary GIS Web Server](http://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/pigwad/down/mars_dl.htm) (PIGWAD, and no I'm not making
  that up)
- [Mars Open Planetary Data](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/2012-08-26-mapping-mars/)
- [Arizona State University Mars Global Datasets](http://www.mars.asu.edu/data/)